# Sonar major alert for using FileOutputStream with CSVWriter

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, sonarqube

In a spring boot application (Java 1.8), we are using CSWriter to write some data on CSV files.

We are also using Sonar to control code smells and coverage.

I'm having trouble with one of the major alert from Sonar on this code:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(directory + File.separator + csv, true), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

Sonar tell me to use new ways to create stream from Java 1.7:

> This method creates and uses a java.io.FileInputStream or java.io.FileOutputStream object. Unfortunately both of these classes implement a finalize method, which means that objects created will likely hang around until a full garbage collection occurs, which will leave excessive garbage on the heap for longer, and potentially much longer than expected. Java 7 introduced two ways to create streams for reading and writing files that do not have this concern. You should consider switching from these above classes to InputStream is = java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(myfile.toPath()); OutputStream os = java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(myfile.toPath());

I don't know how to deal with this bug, as OutputStreamWriter waiting for an OutputStream. Any of you had the same issue ? Should i choose an other CSV manager ?

Comment: Have you considered doing exactly what it says in the exception message? Ot you could try [Files.newBufferedWriter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) in one or other of its overloads. That way Sonar won't see the underlying stream.

Comment: @monthix - did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of FileOutputStream you can use something like that:

```
File file = new File("pathName");
OutputStream os = java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(file.toPath());
final CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

I don't have Sonar configured, so no sure if it's fine now.

On the other hand you can use try-with-resources to close stream just after the try clause.